# GoLang Convert C.wchar_t to go string

Tags: c++, go, dll

I am looking to convert a `[32]C.wchar_t` to a go string.

The array is defined as follows in the `dll` I am talking to:

```
typedef struct myStruct {
    WCHAR someString[32];
}
```

I am defining the struct in go as follows:

```
type myStruct struct {
    someString [32]C.wchar_t
}
```

I have a method in the `dll`:

```
DLLINTERFACE HRESULT __stdcall GetMyStruct (myStruct* ptrMyStruct);
```

This method will populate the `someString` field of `myStruct`.

I am calling the method like so (this is working correctly, I think, I have not been able to see the contents of `someString`):

```
func getMyStruct() (*myStruct, uintptr) {
    var getMyStruct = dll.MustFindProc("GetMyStruct")
    var args = new(myStruct)
    ret, _, _ := getMyStruct .Call(uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(args)))

    fmt.Printf("Return: %d\n", (int)(ret))
    return args, ret
}
```

I need to convert `someString` to a go string. I have tried using `"github.com/GeertJohan/cgo.wchar"`, but it does not have a method for converting `[]C.whar_t` to go string.

Currently I'm not sure if my go struct is correct. I'm also not sure if I am initializing `myStruct` correctly before sending it to the dll.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, `wchar_t` is normally UTF-16 (little-endian). They don't normally start with a BOM (which is present so a decoder can detect if they are stored in big or little endian form).

There is a [utf16](https://golang.org/pkg/unicode/utf16/) package but this only translates individual runes. However, there is an additional [unicode](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/text/encoding/unicode) text encoding package that can help.

You would probably do something like this:

```
dec:=unicode.UTF16(unicode.LittleEndian,unicode.UseBOM).NewDecoder()
out,err:= dec.Bytes(([]byte)(unsafe.Pointer(args.someString)))
if err!=nil {
    //handle error
}
// Strings are null terminated, only want content up to null byte
i:=bytes.IndexByte(out,0)
if i==-1 {
   i = len(out)
}
s:=string(out[:i])
```

However, I'd be tempted to declare `someString` as `[64]byte` which is the amount of bytes that a 32 character (16 bites = 2 bytes per character) would need. This would avoid the unsafe typecasting but otherwise should work as above.

*I'm doing this off the top of my head so the code above is meant as an example & may not necessarily work - use at your peril :-)*

Answer (score 0):

It seems GeertJohan's library hasn't been updated for the more recent cgo changes, but a fork has, try [github.com/vitaminwater/cgo.wchar](https://github.com/vitaminwater/cgo.wchar) ([godoc](http://godoc.org/github.com/vitaminwater/cgo.wchar)) instead.

If the C function writes to a C type, pass a variable of the C type.

A (dodgy) example:

```
package main

/*
#include <wchar.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct myStruct {
    wchar_t someString[32];
} myStruct;

wchar_t sample[6] = {0x0048, 0x0069, 0x0020, 0x4e16, 0x754c, 0};

void writeSample(myStruct *m) {
    memcpy(m->someString, &sample, sizeof(wchar_t) * 6);
}
*/
import "C"
import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "unsafe"

    "github.com/vitaminwater/cgo.wchar"
)

func main() {

    m := C.myStruct{}

    C.writeSample(&m)

    s, err := wchar.WcharStringPtrToGoString(unsafe.Pointer(&m.someString))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(s)
}
```

This outputs:

`Hi 世界`

Answer (score 0):

The [`golang.org/x/sys/windows`](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/sys/windows) library provides the [`UTF16PtrToString`](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/sys/windows#UTF16PtrToString) function which does exactly what you need. There's also `UTF16PtrFromString` for converting the other direction.

```golang
import "golang.org/x/sys/windows"

type myStruct struct {
    someString [32]C.wchar_t
}

func (obj *myStruct) SomeString() string {
    return windows.UTF16PtrToString((*uint16)(&obj.someString[0]))
}
```